# Google Map is only visible sometimes in Angular App

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, google-maps

I am having an issue where my google map is only showing some times. Most of the times my place markers can be seen, even when there is no map. Other times everything shows and works as it should.

> **Edit:** I have noticed that the map displays correctly, when I add
>   another map placeholder (like the HTML code below), and the code runs
>   twice.

```
<div ng-show="false">
    <og-google-map twitter="twitterLocations" instagram="instagramLocations"></og-google-map>
</div>
```

I am not sure whether it is a case where my map has not downloaded or rendered, or whether it is hidden.

However, in the developer tools, I have picked up the following changes in my `<div>` where my map is rendered: **When the map displays, there are 2 `<div>`s with a "`transform-origin`" style attribute.**

See images below:

**When the map is showing:**

[image]

**When the map is not showing:**

[image]

The  with `transform-origin` expanded:

[image]

Here is the code I use:

**I am making use of the following Angular Directive for the map:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('portalDashboardApp')
  .directive('ogGoogleMap', function ($http, $q) {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
              twitter: '=',
              instagram: '='
          },
          template: '<div id="gmaps"></div>',
          replace: true,
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

              var map, infoWindow;
              var markers = [];

              // map config
              var mapOptions = {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-0.013026, 21.333860),
                  zoom: 4,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };

              // init the map
              function initMap() {
                  if (map === void 0) {
                      map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);
                  }
              }

              // place a marker
              function setMarker(map, position, title, content, icon) {

                  if (icon === 'IN') {
                      icon = 'images/instagramMarker.png';
                  }
                  else {
                      icon = 'images/twitterMarker.png';
                  }

                  var marker;
                  var markerOptions = {
                      position: position,
                      map: map,
                      title: title,
                      icon: icon
                  };

                  marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
                  markers.push(marker); // add marker to array

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                      // close window if not undefined
                      if (infoWindow !== void 0) {
                          infoWindow.close();
                      }
                      // create new window
                      var infoWindowOptions = {
                          content: content
                      };
                      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
                      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                  });
              }

              function getMentionAddress(latitude, longitude) {

                  var addressData = $q.defer();

                  $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude + ',' + longitude)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        addressData.resolve(data.results[0].formatted_address);
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status) {
                        console.error('Google Maps API error', status, data);
                    });

                  return addressData.promise;

              }

              function deleteCurrentMarkers() {
                  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                      markers[i].setMap(null);
                  }
                  markers = [];
              }

              scope.$watch('instagram', function () {
                  deleteCurrentMarkers();
                  populateMarkers(scope.twitter, 'TW');
                  populateMarkers(scope.instagram, 'IN');
              });

              // show the map and place some markers
              initMap();

              function populateMarkers(locationArray, type) {

                  angular.forEach(locationArray, function (location) {

                      setMarker(map, new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]), '', '', type);

                  });

              }

          }
      };
  });
```

**This is my HTML placeholder for the map:**

```
<div ng-show="!demographics.showDemographicsGraph">
    <og-google-map twitter="twitterLocations" instagram="instagramLocations"></og-google-map>
</div>
```

**This is my CSS:**

```
#gmaps {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you please share you code in plunker

Comment: The project is too big to add to plunker :(

Comment: What is you exact requirement so that i will post my code

Comment: Well, I would like to know why my maps are only showing occasionally. And how to fix that. And like I mentioned with my update, it shows when adding another placeholder for the map, but hiding it. So in effect, the Angular Directive for my map runs twice, and then it shows every time. I cannot think that this is related to un-returned data, as stepping through the code is the same both times, and the data is present both times. Any suggestions what the issue might be?

Comment: How are you loading the google-maps script? Maybe asynchronous and it is to slow sometimes?

Comment: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDZ...."></script>` in my index.html and the calls in the Directive in my question. I assume the script will then be loaded and it is when the Directive calls the google maps api when the map should be created. I also think it could be an async issue. Any suggestions?